# Tag formatting doesn't hide with spoiler quotes

Tags: bug, markdown, spoilers

The tag doesn't hide:

> Spoiler Quote
>  [tag](/questions/tagged/tag)
>  Look, not hidden!

Comment: Well, no risk of spoiler being compromised as the text is still hidden, but yeah it doesn't look very good. :/

Comment: @ShadowWizard yeah, this is (imo) worse than the images "appearing" not fading.

Comment: Ah, the last paragraph...